# How to exclude an array from search in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, search

I've an array. Let's say;

```
private string[] WhiteList =
     {
        "abcxyz.cs",
        "mouseapi.dll",
        "SensitivtyFix.asi",
        "drake.mp3"
     };
```

Now I want to exclude that array from a directory/file search. How do I achieve that?

For this search, I'm using another array called BlackList from which I could fetch desired files but I'm unable to exclude files from the array Whitelist.

```
for (int i = 0; i < GetSize; ++i)
        {
            foreach (var File in DirInf.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories))
            {
                if (File.FullName.Contains(Blacklist[i]) && !File.FullName.Contains(WhiteList[i]))

                {
                    listBox1.Items.Add("File: " + File.FullName);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: You mean, exclude the file names in the array?

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes, I want the search to return with BlackList filters and exclude the files given in array Whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

The condition you need (for use with LINQ `Where` function) is

```
Predicate<FileInfo> filter =
      f => Array.Exists(blackList, f.FullName.Contains) && 
             !Array.Exists(whiteList, f.FullName.Contains);
```

The problem with your original code is that it looked at `blackList[i]` and `whiteList` AT THE SAME `i`, but the list index that matches might be different.

Now you may fill your list box:

```
foreach (var file in DirectoryInfo.GetFiles("*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Where(filter))
    listBox1.Items.Add(file);
```

Comment: I think you mean `Any` not `Exists` since `Exists` is a method of `List` and these are actually arrays.

Comment: @juharr: It's named [`Exists`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yw84x8be(v=vs.110).aspx) for arrays also, but is static.  Thanks for pointing out the problem, I probably keyed in on the variable names and thought they really were lists.

Answer (score -1):

YOu need

```
 if (BlackList.Contains(File.FullName) && !WHiteList.Contains(File.FullName)))
```

although that seems odd, since you can just not put the whitelist names in the blacklist. Maybe you need || not &&

Comment: Not that odd, perhaps blacklist contains `rake` and whitelist contains (as in question) `drake.mp3`

Comment: And that shows what's wrong with your suggestion -- according to the question one of the items in the list is contained (partial match) within the filename.  The whole filename won't be in the list.

Comment: Blacklist contains a list of files with different extensions like .cs so it returns with a big list of files with .cs extension. I need files in Whitelist which have .cs extension to be excluded from the result. I hope it's clear.